# JavaScript group data into tree view 2 levels deep

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JSON object like this:

```
{
    id: '1', 
    items: [
        {
            id: '1',
            saleId: '123',
            saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
            locationId: '123',
            itemCode: '456',
            itemDescription: 'my item',
            categoryCode: '555',
            categoryDescription: 'my category',
            qty: 10,
            saleValue: 200
        },
        {
            id: '1',
            saleId: '123',
            saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
            locationId: '123',
            itemCode: '456',
            itemDescription: 'my item',
            categoryCode: '555',
            categoryDescription: 'my category',
            qty: 10,
            saleValue: 200
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: '2', 
    items: [
        {
            id: '2',
            saleId: '123',
            saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
            locationId: '123',
            itemCode: '456',
            itemDescription: 'my item',
            categoryCode: '556',
            categoryDescription: 'my category 6',
            qty: 10,
            saleValue: 200
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: '3', 
    items: [
        {
            venueId: '3',
            saleId: '123',
            saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
            locationId: '123',
            itemCode: '456',
            itemDescription: 'my item',
            categoryCode: '557',
            categoryDescription: 'my category 7',
            qty: 10,
            saleValue: 200
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to make this into a new JSON object where everything is grouped by id (it already is but I need the number to become the key) then by categoryCode so the result looks something like this:

```
{
    '1': { 
        '555': { 
            id: '1',
            saleId: '123',
            saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
            locationId: '123',
            itemCode: '456',
            itemDescription: 'my item',
            categoryCode: '555',
            categoryDescription: 'my category',
            qty: 10,
            saleValue: 200
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this either using lodash or just plain JavaScript or some NPM package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a general function that receiving array of items and parse it based on attrKeys and infoKeys array:

```js
const data = [{
      id: '1',
      items: [{
        id: '1',
        saleId: '123',
        saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
        locationId: '123',
        itemCode: '456',
        itemDescription: 'my item',
        categoryCode: '555',
        categoryDescription: 'my category',
        qty: 10,
        saleValue: 200
      }, {
        id: '1',
        saleId: '123',
        saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
        locationId: '123',
        itemCode: '456',
        itemDescription: 'my item',
        categoryCode: '555',
        categoryDescription: 'my category',
        qty: 10,
        saleValue: 200
      }]
    }, {
      id: '2',
      items: [{
        id: '2',
        saleId: '123',
        saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
        locationId: '123',
        itemCode: '456',
        itemDescription: 'my item',
        categoryCode: '556',
        categoryDescription: 'my category 6',
        qty: 10,
        saleValue: 200
      }]
    }, {
      id: '3',
      items: [{
        venueId: '3',
        saleId: '123',
        saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
        locationId: '123',
        itemCode: '456',
        itemDescription: 'my item',
        categoryCode: '557',
        categoryDescription: 'my category 7',
        qty: 10,
        saleValue: 200
      }]
    }];
    
   const transformData = (input, attrKeys = [], infoKeys = [], deep = 0) => {
          if (input && typeof input === 'object' && input.length) {
            const key1 = attrKeys[deep];
            const key2 = infoKeys[deep];
            deep++;
            const output = {}
    
            input.forEach(i => {
              const info = i[key2] ? transformData(i[key2], attrKeys, infoKeys, deep) : i;
    
              output[`${i[key1]}`] = info;
            });
    
            return output;
          }
    
          return input;
        };
    
//What you want is here
const transformedData = transformData(data,  ['id','categoryCode'], ['items'])
console.log({transformedData})
```

Comment: Do you have a code snippet? I cannot get this to run on an editor.

Comment: just copy and paste into browser. Let me try to put in snippet

Comment: @bex please check :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the nested `for...of` loop approach:

```js
const data = [{
  id: '1',
  items: [{
    id: '1',
    saleId: '123',
    saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
    locationId: '123',
    itemCode: '456',
    itemDescription: 'my item',
    categoryCode: '555',
    categoryDescription: 'my category',
    qty: 10,
    saleValue: 200
  }, {
    id: '1',
    saleId: '123',
    saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
    locationId: '123',
    itemCode: '456',
    itemDescription: 'my item',
    categoryCode: '555',
    categoryDescription: 'my category',
    qty: 10,
    saleValue: 200
  }]
}, {
  id: '2',
  items: [{
    id: '2',
    saleId: '123',
    saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
    locationId: '123',
    itemCode: '456',
    itemDescription: 'my item',
    categoryCode: '556',
    categoryDescription: 'my category 6',
    qty: 10,
    saleValue: 200
  }]
}, {
  id: '3',
  items: [{
    venueId: '3',
    saleId: '123',
    saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
    locationId: '123',
    itemCode: '456',
    itemDescription: 'my item',
    categoryCode: '557',
    categoryDescription: 'my category 7',
    qty: 10,
    saleValue: 200
  }]
}];

let finalData = {};
for (let obj of data) {
  finalData[obj.id] = {};
  for (var item of obj.items) {
    finalData[obj.id][item.categoryCode] = { ...item
    };
  }
}

console.log(finalData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.reduce function to achieve it.

```js
const array = [{
 id: '1',
 items: [
  {
   id: '1',
   saleId: '123',
   saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
   locationId: '123',
   itemCode: '456',
   itemDescription: 'my item',
   categoryCode: '555',
   categoryDescription: 'my category',
   qty: 10,
   saleValue: 200
  },
  {
   id: '1',
   saleId: '123',
   saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
   locationId: '123',
   itemCode: '456',
   itemDescription: 'my item',
   categoryCode: '555',
   categoryDescription: 'my category',
   qty: 10,
   saleValue: 200
  }
 ]
},
{
 id: '2',
 items: [
  {
   id: '2',
   saleId: '123',
   saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
   locationId: '123',
   itemCode: '456',
   itemDescription: 'my item',
   categoryCode: '556',
   categoryDescription: 'my category 6',
   qty: 10,
   saleValue: 200
  }
 ]
},
{
 id: '3',
 items: [
  {
   id: '3',
   saleId: '123',
   saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
   locationId: '123',
   itemCode: '456',
   itemDescription: 'my item',
   categoryCode: '557',
   categoryDescription: 'my category 7',
   qty: 10,
   saleValue: 200
  }
 ]
}];


console.log(
 array
  // flatten the items array
  .reduce((prev, curr) => {
   return prev.concat(curr.items);
  }, [])
  .reduce((prev, curr) => {
   if (!prev[curr.id])
    prev[curr.id] = {};
   if (!prev[curr.id][curr.categoryCode])
    prev[curr.id][curr.categoryCode] = {};
   prev[curr.id][curr.categoryCode] = curr;
   return prev;
  }, {})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can archive that by just 7 lines of code using reduce function.

```js
const array = [
    {
        id: '1',
        items: [
            {
                id: '1',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '456',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '555',
                categoryDescription: 'my category',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            },
            {
                id: '1',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '456',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '555',
                categoryDescription: 'my category',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        items: [
            {
                id: '2',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '456',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '556',
                categoryDescription: 'my category 6',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        items: [
            {
                venueId: '3',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '456',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '557',
                categoryDescription: 'my category 7',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            }
        ]
    }
];

console.log(
    array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        prev[curr.id] = curr.items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
            (prev[curr.categoryCode] = []).push(curr);
            return prev;
        }, {});
        return prev;
    }, {})
);
```