# JavaScript group data into tree view 2 levels deep and the final level to be an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I have a JSON object like this:

```
[
  {
    "venueId": "10001",
    "items": [
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1604",
        "itemDescription": "Chef Instruction",
        "categoryCode": "28",
        "categoryDescription": "Food Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1381",
        "itemDescription": "Meat Lovers Pizza",
        "categoryCode": "48",
        "categoryDescription": "25Fore - Pizza",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1027",
        "itemDescription": "Sweet Spot Latte  Mug",
        "categoryCode": "23",
        "categoryDescription": "Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "1413",
        "itemDescription": "Garlic Bread",
        "categoryCode": "51",
        "categoryDescription": "25Fore - Starters",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "51",
        "itemDescription": "Cascade Light Schooner",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "827",
        "itemDescription": "Banrock Station Moscato 1L",
        "categoryCode": "15",
        "categoryDescription": "Wine White",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "1192",
        "itemDescription": "Apple Slice",
        "categoryCode": "31",
        "categoryDescription": "Cafe Gold - Cake Selection",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "301",
        "itemDescription": "Tooheys New 6pk",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "12",
        "itemCode": "1036",
        "itemDescription": "Cappuccino 16oz",
        "categoryCode": "23",
        "categoryDescription": "Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "12",
        "itemCode": "61",
        "itemDescription": "Great Northern Orig Pint",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "12",
        "itemCode": "1232",
        "itemDescription": "Asst. Cheese/Crackers 5pce",
        "categoryCode": "33",
        "categoryDescription": "Cafe Gold - Savoury Cabinet",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "863",
        "itemDescription": "Lindemans Bin 85 P/Grigio 250",
        "categoryCode": "15",
        "categoryDescription": "Wine White",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "1600",
        "itemDescription": "Lemon/Lime Bitters Glass",
        "categoryCode": "7",
        "categoryDescription": "Postmix",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "1143",
        "itemDescription": "Chocolate",
        "categoryCode": "28",
        "categoryDescription": "Food Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "491",
        "itemDescription": "Coke 330ml",
        "categoryCode": "9",
        "categoryDescription": "Soft Drink",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "335",
        "itemDescription": "Postmix Glass",
        "categoryCode": "7",
        "categoryDescription": "Postmix",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "68",
        "itemDescription": "Great Northern Super Crisp Po",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1286",
        "itemDescription": "Mushroom Sauce",
        "categoryCode": "36",
        "categoryDescription": "Sauce Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1604",
        "itemDescription": "Chef Instruction",
        "categoryCode": "28",
        "categoryDescription": "Food Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1831",
        "itemDescription": "Ginger Beer Crows Nest 330ml",
        "categoryCode": "9",
        "categoryDescription": "Soft Drink",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1105",
        "itemDescription": "Filo/Salad",
        "categoryCode": "26",
        "categoryDescription": "Sweet Spot - Savoury Cabinet",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1187",
        "itemDescription": "Cafe Gold Pie 4 n 20",
        "categoryCode": "30",
        "categoryDescription": "Cafe Gold - Bar Menu",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1360",
        "itemDescription": "Extra-Lamb Shank",
        "categoryCode": "50",
        "categoryDescription": "25Fore - Specials",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1296",
        "itemDescription": "Side Chips",
        "categoryCode": "36",
        "categoryDescription": "Sauce Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1808",
        "itemDescription": "Add Reef Topper ",
        "categoryCode": "52",
        "categoryDescription": "25Fore - Toppers",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1224",
        "itemDescription": "Cafe Gold Long Black Mug",
        "categoryCode": "32",
        "categoryDescription": "Cafe Gold - Coffee/Tea",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "43",
        "itemDescription": "Carlton Mid Pint",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "21",
        "itemDescription": "Canadian Club/Dry Schooner",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "105",
        "itemDescription": "XXXX Gold Schooner",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "1027",
        "itemDescription": "Sweet Spot Latte  Mug",
        "categoryCode": "23",
        "categoryDescription": "Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "301",
        "itemDescription": "Tooheys New 6pk",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1639",
        "itemDescription": "Upper Area",
        "categoryCode": "87",
        "categoryDescription": "Seating Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "335",
        "itemDescription": "Postmix Glass",
        "categoryCode": "7",
        "categoryDescription": "Postmix",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "491",
        "itemDescription": "Coke 330ml",
        "categoryCode": "9",
        "categoryDescription": "Soft Drink",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "43",
        "itemDescription": "Carlton Mid Pint",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "1330",
        "itemDescription": "200g Rump",
        "categoryCode": "40",
        "categoryDescription": "25Fore - From The Grill",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "17",
        "itemCode": "1462",
        "itemDescription": "Lactose Free Milk ",
        "categoryCode": "54",
        "categoryDescription": "Coffee Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1625",
        "itemDescription": "Chicken",
        "categoryCode": "28",
        "categoryDescription": "Food Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "43",
        "itemDescription": "Carlton Mid Pint",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "14",
        "itemCode": "1725",
        "itemDescription": "THURS T-Bone",
        "categoryCode": "46",
        "categoryDescription": "25Fore - Nightly Specials",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "1261",
        "itemDescription": "Well Done",
        "categoryCode": "35",
        "categoryDescription": "Cooking Instructions",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "104",
        "itemDescription": "XXXX Gold Pot",
        "categoryCode": "4",
        "categoryDescription": "Bulk Beer",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      },
      {
        "venueId": "10001",
        "locationId": "15",
        "itemCode": "1411",
        "itemDescription": "Bread Roll",
        "categoryCode": "51",
        "categoryDescription": "25Fore - Starters",
        "qty": 0,
        "saleValue": 0,
        "saleDatetime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timeToLive": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to make this into a new JSON object where everything is grouped by id (it already is but I need the number to become the key) then by categoryCode so the result looks something like this:

```
{
    '1': { 
        '555': [{ itemCode: '456'}, { itemCode: '457'}, { itemCode: '458'}]
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this either using lodash or just plain JavaScript or some NPM package?
This is similar to this question: [JavaScript group data into tree view 2 levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368892/javascript-group-data-into-tree-view-2-levels-deep)
but the difference is that the third level is an array of objects.

Comment: Your example is not valid JSON. It is also not a valid JavaScript expression. Did you mean to enclose the objects in an array?

Comment: yes, so I want to group by id, then categoryCode and then a collection of the object because 1 id can have many categoryCodes  and 1 categoryCode  can have many itemCodes

Answer (score 1):

You could take two nested loops and create new objects/arrays, if necessary for the groups.

```js
var data = [{ venueId: "10001", items: [{ venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1604", itemDescription: "Chef Instruction", categoryCode: "28", categoryDescription: "Food Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1381", itemDescription: "Meat Lovers Pizza", categoryCode: "48", categoryDescription: "25Fore - Pizza", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1027", itemDescription: "Sweet Spot Latte  Mug", categoryCode: "23", categoryDescription: "Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "1413", itemDescription: "Garlic Bread", categoryCode: "51", categoryDescription: "25Fore - Starters", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "51", itemDescription: "Cascade Light Schooner", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "827", itemDescription: "Banrock Station Moscato 1L", categoryCode: "15", categoryDescription: "Wine White", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "1192", itemDescription: "Apple Slice", categoryCode: "31", categoryDescription: "Cafe Gold - Cake Selection", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "301", itemDescription: "Tooheys New 6pk", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "12", itemCode: "1036", itemDescription: "Cappuccino 16oz", categoryCode: "23", categoryDescription: "Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "12", itemCode: "61", itemDescription: "Great Northern Orig Pint", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "12", itemCode: "1232", itemDescription: "Asst. Cheese/Crackers 5pce", categoryCode: "33", categoryDescription: "Cafe Gold - Savoury Cabinet", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "863", itemDescription: "Lindemans Bin 85 P/Grigio 250", categoryCode: "15", categoryDescription: "Wine White", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "1600", itemDescription: "Lemon/Lime Bitters Glass", categoryCode: "7", categoryDescription: "Postmix", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "1143", itemDescription: "Chocolate", categoryCode: "28", categoryDescription: "Food Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "491", itemDescription: "Coke 330ml", categoryCode: "9", categoryDescription: "Soft Drink", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "335", itemDescription: "Postmix Glass", categoryCode: "7", categoryDescription: "Postmix", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "68", itemDescription: "Great Northern Super Crisp Po", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1286", itemDescription: "Mushroom Sauce", categoryCode: "36", categoryDescription: "Sauce Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1604", itemDescription: "Chef Instruction", categoryCode: "28", categoryDescription: "Food Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1831", itemDescription: "Ginger Beer Crows Nest 330ml", categoryCode: "9", categoryDescription: "Soft Drink", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1105", itemDescription: "Filo/Salad", categoryCode: "26", categoryDescription: "Sweet Spot - Savoury Cabinet", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1187", itemDescription: "Cafe Gold Pie 4 n 20", categoryCode: "30", categoryDescription: "Cafe Gold - Bar Menu", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1360", itemDescription: "Extra-Lamb Shank", categoryCode: "50", categoryDescription: "25Fore - Specials", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1296", itemDescription: "Side Chips", categoryCode: "36", categoryDescription: "Sauce Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1808", itemDescription: "Add Reef Topper ", categoryCode: "52", categoryDescription: "25Fore - Toppers", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1224", itemDescription: "Cafe Gold Long Black Mug", categoryCode: "32", categoryDescription: "Cafe Gold - Coffee/Tea", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "43", itemDescription: "Carlton Mid Pint", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "21", itemDescription: "Canadian Club/Dry Schooner", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "105", itemDescription: "XXXX Gold Schooner", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "1027", itemDescription: "Sweet Spot Latte  Mug", categoryCode: "23", categoryDescription: "Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "301", itemDescription: "Tooheys New 6pk", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1639", itemDescription: "Upper Area", categoryCode: "87", categoryDescription: "Seating Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "335", itemDescription: "Postmix Glass", categoryCode: "7", categoryDescription: "Postmix", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "491", itemDescription: "Coke 330ml", categoryCode: "9", categoryDescription: "Soft Drink", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "43", itemDescription: "Carlton Mid Pint", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "1330", itemDescription: "200g Rump", categoryCode: "40", categoryDescription: "25Fore - From The Grill", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "17", itemCode: "1462", itemDescription: "Lactose Free Milk ", categoryCode: "54", categoryDescription: "Coffee Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1625", itemDescription: "Chicken", categoryCode: "28", categoryDescription: "Food Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "43", itemDescription: "Carlton Mid Pint", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "14", itemCode: "1725", itemDescription: "THURS T-Bone", categoryCode: "46", categoryDescription: "25Fore - Nightly Specials", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "1261", itemDescription: "Well Done", categoryCode: "35", categoryDescription: "Cooking Instructions", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "104", itemDescription: "XXXX Gold Pot", categoryCode: "4", categoryDescription: "Bulk Beer", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }, { venueId: "10001", locationId: "15", itemCode: "1411", itemDescription: "Bread Roll", categoryCode: "51", categoryDescription: "25Fore - Starters", qty: 0, saleValue: 0, saleDatetime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", timeToLive: 0 }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { items }) => {
        items.forEach(({ itemCode, ...item }) => ['venueId', 'categoryCode']
            .reduce((o, k, i) => o[item[k]] = o[item[k]] || (i ? [] : {}), r)
            .push({ itemCode })
        );
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have fixed the json above but this code does not work with it

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to do a simple double loop. Once over the different rows you have, and then over the items. Then, in these loops, you fill the final object with the desired structure:

```js
var initialArray = [
    {
        id: '1', 
        items: [
            {
                id: '1',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '456',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '555',
                categoryDescription: 'my category',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            },
            {
                id: '1',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '457',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '555',
                categoryDescription: 'my category',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            },
            {
                id: '1',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '458',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '555',
                categoryDescription: 'my category',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '2', 
        items: [
            {
                id: '2',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '456',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '556',
                categoryDescription: 'my category 6',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '3', 
        items: [
            {
                venueId: '3',
                saleId: '123',
                saleIdAndItemId: '123456',
                locationId: '123',
                itemCode: '457',
                itemDescription: 'my item',
                categoryCode: '557',
                categoryDescription: 'my category 7',
                qty: 10,
                saleValue: 200
            }
        ]
    }
];

var finalObject = {},
    currentRow = {},
    currentItem = {},
    newItemObject = {};

for (var i in initialArray) {
    currentRow = initialArray[i];
    newItemObject = {};
    for (var j in currentRow.items) {
        currentItem = currentRow.items[j];
        // this if is in case there are different category codes in the item array
        if (!newItemObject.hasOwnProperty(currentItem.categoryCode)) {
            newItemObject[currentItem.categoryCode] = [];
        }
        // you could just push the entire currentItem if you want all the data
        // newItemObject[currentItem.categoryCode].push(currentItem);
        newItemObject[currentItem.categoryCode].push({
            'itemCode': currentItem.itemCode
        });
    }
    
    finalObject[currentRow.id] = newItemObject;
}

console.log(finalObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your linked related question, you seemed to want more properties than you listed here in this example. Here is a function that will transform your data into the requested format, optionally allowing you to specify which nested keys you want to include in your output:

```js
const transformData = (array, keysToInclude) => {
  const result = {};
  for (const group of array) {
    const id = {};
    result[group.venueId] = id;
    for (const item of group.items) {
      let category = id[item.categoryCode];
      if (!category) {
        category = [];
        id[item.categoryCode] = category;
      }
      if (!keysToInclude) {
        category.push(item);
        continue;
      }
      const itemData = {};
      for (const key of keysToInclude) {
        if (Object.keys(item).includes(key)) itemData[key] = item[key];
      }
      category.push(itemData);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const data=[{venueId:"10001",items:[{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1604",itemDescription:"Chef Instruction",categoryCode:"28",categoryDescription:"Food Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1381",itemDescription:"Meat Lovers Pizza",categoryCode:"48",categoryDescription:"25Fore - Pizza",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1027",itemDescription:"Sweet Spot Latte  Mug",categoryCode:"23",categoryDescription:"Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"1413",itemDescription:"Garlic Bread",categoryCode:"51",categoryDescription:"25Fore - Starters",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"51",itemDescription:"Cascade Light Schooner",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"827",itemDescription:"Banrock Station Moscato 1L",categoryCode:"15",categoryDescription:"Wine White",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"1192",itemDescription:"Apple Slice",categoryCode:"31",categoryDescription:"Cafe Gold - Cake Selection",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"301",itemDescription:"Tooheys New 6pk",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"12",itemCode:"1036",itemDescription:"Cappuccino 16oz",categoryCode:"23",categoryDescription:"Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"12",itemCode:"61",itemDescription:"Great Northern Orig Pint",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"12",itemCode:"1232",itemDescription:"Asst. Cheese/Crackers 5pce",categoryCode:"33",categoryDescription:"Cafe Gold - Savoury Cabinet",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"863",itemDescription:"Lindemans Bin 85 P/Grigio 250",categoryCode:"15",categoryDescription:"Wine White",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"1600",itemDescription:"Lemon/Lime Bitters Glass",categoryCode:"7",categoryDescription:"Postmix",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"1143",itemDescription:"Chocolate",categoryCode:"28",categoryDescription:"Food Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"491",itemDescription:"Coke 330ml",categoryCode:"9",categoryDescription:"Soft Drink",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"335",itemDescription:"Postmix Glass",categoryCode:"7",categoryDescription:"Postmix",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"68",itemDescription:"Great Northern Super Crisp Po",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1286",itemDescription:"Mushroom Sauce",categoryCode:"36",categoryDescription:"Sauce Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1604",itemDescription:"Chef Instruction",categoryCode:"28",categoryDescription:"Food Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1831",itemDescription:"Ginger Beer Crows Nest 330ml",categoryCode:"9",categoryDescription:"Soft Drink",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1105",itemDescription:"Filo/Salad",categoryCode:"26",categoryDescription:"Sweet Spot - Savoury Cabinet",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1187",itemDescription:"Cafe Gold Pie 4 n 20",categoryCode:"30",categoryDescription:"Cafe Gold - Bar Menu",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1360",itemDescription:"Extra-Lamb Shank",categoryCode:"50",categoryDescription:"25Fore - Specials",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1296",itemDescription:"Side Chips",categoryCode:"36",categoryDescription:"Sauce Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1808",itemDescription:"Add Reef Topper ",categoryCode:"52",categoryDescription:"25Fore - Toppers",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1224",itemDescription:"Cafe Gold Long Black Mug",categoryCode:"32",categoryDescription:"Cafe Gold - Coffee/Tea",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"43",itemDescription:"Carlton Mid Pint",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"21",itemDescription:"Canadian Club/Dry Schooner",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"105",itemDescription:"XXXX Gold Schooner",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"1027",itemDescription:"Sweet Spot Latte  Mug",categoryCode:"23",categoryDescription:"Sweet Spot - Coffee/Tea",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"301",itemDescription:"Tooheys New 6pk",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1639",itemDescription:"Upper Area",categoryCode:"87",categoryDescription:"Seating Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"335",itemDescription:"Postmix Glass",categoryCode:"7",categoryDescription:"Postmix",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"491",itemDescription:"Coke 330ml",categoryCode:"9",categoryDescription:"Soft Drink",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"43",itemDescription:"Carlton Mid Pint",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"1330",itemDescription:"200g Rump",categoryCode:"40",categoryDescription:"25Fore - From The Grill",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"17",itemCode:"1462",itemDescription:"Lactose Free Milk ",categoryCode:"54",categoryDescription:"Coffee Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1625",itemDescription:"Chicken",categoryCode:"28",categoryDescription:"Food Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"43",itemDescription:"Carlton Mid Pint",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"14",itemCode:"1725",itemDescription:"THURS T-Bone",categoryCode:"46",categoryDescription:"25Fore - Nightly Specials",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"1261",itemDescription:"Well Done",categoryCode:"35",categoryDescription:"Cooking Instructions",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"104",itemDescription:"XXXX Gold Pot",categoryCode:"4",categoryDescription:"Bulk Beer",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0},{venueId:"10001",locationId:"15",itemCode:"1411",itemDescription:"Bread Roll",categoryCode:"51",categoryDescription:"25Fore - Starters",qty:0,saleValue:0,saleDatetime:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",timeToLive:0}]}];

const onlyItemCodes = transformData(data, ['itemCode']);
const allKeys = transformData(data);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

log(onlyItemCodes);
log(allKeys);
```

Comment: I like your answer but it does not seem to work with this data

Comment: I just changed the data above

Comment: @bex Let us know when you're done changing the details of your question, and its contents are finalized so that we can provide relevant answers. If you keep changing the data format, it's unlikely the answers you receive will be relevant to you.